# Is there a way to use a GPS message to set computer date and time

Tags: gps, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a robot with a GPS and an OBC. I need to set up the date/time of the OBC each time it boots. I would like to use the GPS ros driver/navsatfix message to do that. Is there a package or a node to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406559/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-gps-message-to-set-computer-date-and-time/) by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2022-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Ahoy there!** I be assumin' OBC refers to just a generic on-board-computer. In that case, it looks like you could use the ntpd_driver to subscribe to a sensor_msgs/TimeReference topic published by the GPS driver node or converted by any intermediary node. See this previous ros answers post for more info:

https://answers.ros.org/question/372848/synchronize-linux-against-pps-clock-with-piksi-multi-rtk/?answer=380317#post-id-380317

Looks like the same package is supported in the latest LTS release of ROS2 as well:

https://index.ros.org/r/ntpd_driver/#humble

I'd just note to be sure you are using or converting to sensor_msgs/TimeReference message type as intended:

https://answers.ros.org/question/320089/what-is-the-correct-standard-way-of-using-sensor_msgstimereference/

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2022-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2022-09-20**:
that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks